# How does Big Sur determine execute permissions

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, unix

In trying to add programs to the Full Disk Access list it is not clear how Big Sur determines which files are executable and thus addable to the Full Disk Access list.  For instance I have files in /opt/local/bin/automake*

Initially I have automake and automake-1.16 which are hard links to the same inode.  They are thus identical.  Both have exactly the same Unix permissions and no file ACL's.  However in the Finder or in the File browser in System Preferences looking to add executables to the Full File Access list "automake" shows up as a Unix executable and "automake-1.16" shows up as a Document.  Now it gets even more confusing.  If I had a hard link to "automake2" from "automake" then "automake2" shows up in the Finder as a Unix executable.  But also if I make a hard link from "automake-1.16" to "automake3" then "automake3" shows up as a Unix executable in Finder while "automake-1.16" is a Document.

Now there are lots of files in /opt/local/bin which show up as Unix executables and lots that show up as Documents even though they have identical Unix perms (755).  If a program in /opt/local/bin shows up as a Unix executable it can be added to the Full File Access list, if it only shows up as a document it can't.  But there does not seem to be any logical reason for what Unix executable files are considered as such and which are considered documents.

What is going on?

Comment: It this particular case it's the `.16` that makes it show as a **Document** under **Kind** in **Finder**. If you want to add e.g. `automake-1.16` to **Full Disk Access** in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**, then after opening the **Lock** at that location, you can drag and drop e.g. `automake-1.16` _file_ into the _list area_ of that _pane_ for it to be added.

Comment: If Terminal.app has Full Disk Access then do the command line programs need it?